# why javascript regex is throwing error for special characters even after using '\'?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to catch invalid operators passed to eval() function so that it can display `invalid expression` on screen but it's not working. Is there something I am missing? sorry if this sounds silly but I am beginner to JavaScript.

```
function evaluating(el){
    var invalidOperators = ['//','**','+/','/+','+*','*+','-/','/-','-*','/*','*/'];
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<invalidOperators.length;i++){
        if(el.search(invalidOperators[i])!= -1){
            document.getElementById('display').value = 'INVALID SYNTAX';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('display').value = eval(el);
        }
        }
    }
```

I tried adding `\` to all strings in `invalidOperators` as for special characters of regex but it's still not working.

Comment: Is el a String? if so, I think you should try using `indexOf` method instead of `search`. And probably break the loop once invalid syntax is detected.

Comment: You might want to `eval` the string only after the `for` loop.

Comment: @BilalMirza yes, el is a string. the above code works fine if you only have `--` in invalidOperators. it's something about having regex special characters which i am not understanding

Comment: @yunzen I tried doing that but i want the eval part to execute only `if` part is false. If `if ` is `true` I want it to display `INVALID SYNTAX` on screen

Comment: But you will `eval`, if all but one of the invalidOperators are found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't break the loop with `break;`, an invalid string can be found, but immediately after that, the next invalid string isn't found, so in the end you don't get the `INVALID SYNTAX` you're expecting, and that's a false negative.

I would simplify the function and write something like below. Your function should only do one thing, that is, return true or false (depending whether the string is valid or not). Then, use this function inside another function that does only one thing, that is, write `'INVALID SYNTAX'` in a div. The smaller and more specialized a function, the better.

```js
const invalidOperators = ['//','**','+/','/+','+*','*+','-/','/-','-*','/*','*/'];

// returns true if the string to test contains any of the elements in the invalidOperators array
const isInvalid = toTest => invalidOperators.some( e => toTest.includes(e) );

const checkInvalid = event => output.innerHTML = isInvalid(event.target.value) ? "INVALID!!" : "Okay.";
```

```html
<input onkeyup="checkInvalid(event)"/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me to use include() function. however it shows error when you pass string containing `/*` or `*/` @JeremyThille

Comment: No, in my snippet it says INVALID when I type `/*`

Comment: Yes it shows error for some of the strings from invalidOperations and works perfectly fine with other strings. Is it issue of includes()?

Comment: I don't know. What error and what other strings?

Comment: In the given `invalidOperators = ['//','**','+/','/+','+*','*+','-/','/-','-*','/*','*/'];` There are some values like `*/` and `\*` which If detected show `invalid token` error in console and other strings like  `/+` , `-/` that if detected outputs `Invalid syntax` which is what I expect.

Comment: When I type `*/` it shows INVALID with no error (that's good), `\*` shows Okay with no error (that's good too). I can't reproduce your issue, at least in Chrome